# Как добавить php-код в ejs-шаблонизатор?

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы, ejs

Допустим я отправляю ajax-запрос с данными методом post.
Я использую шаблонизатор ejs для вёрстки.  Допустим есть шаблон товара, который в цикле вызывается как-то так:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<4; i++) { %>
   <%- partial('content/product', {data: ? }) %>
<% } %>
```

Этот код нужно вставить в php-скрипт, но вместо `{data: ? }` нужно вставить `$_POST['category']`, чтобы получилось как-то так:
 `<%- partial('content/product', {data: $_POST['category'] }) %>`
т.е. ajax-запрос должен вернуть товары, которые формируются с помощью ejs-шаблонизатора.  Такое вообще возможно?
Если в php-скрипт вставить этот код

```
<% for(var i=0; i<4; i++) { %>
    <%- partial('content/product') %>
<% } %>
```

, то ajax-запрос нормально отрабатывает и возвращает 4 товара, но нужно добавить данные из переменной $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос: никак.

Судя по описанию ejs на официальном сайте - это клиентский шаблонизатор.
PHP-код не выполняется на стороне клиента.

---

Скорее всего для решения вашей задачи нужен комплексный подход с применением ajax, задайте правильный вопрос со всеми необходимыми данными данными и вам на него ответят.

Comment: обновил свой вопрос

Comment: >задайте правильный вопрос со всеми необходимыми данными данными и вам на него ответят.

Comment: Вариант 1: используйте . и '' для конкатенации строк.

Вариант 2: забудьте о правке ejs шаблона на стороне сервера, это порнография, используйте ajax запросы для получения данных и шаблонизатор на стороне пользователя для рендеринга.

Comment: покажите пожалуйста пример, как правильно сделать в моём примере.  
     `<%- partial('content/product', {data: ? }) %>` как здесь нужно правильно добавить $_POST-данные ?

Comment: Не вижу смысла в примере, в документации PHP все уже описано до меня http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php

Comment: про конкатенацию в php я знаю, на как эту конкатенацию применить в ejs? этот код выдаёт ошибку `<%- partial('content/product', {i: i, "$_POST['category']" }) %>`

Comment: Так у вас тут нет никакой конкатенации, судя по коду. 

Еще раз повторяю: ejs НЕ работает на стороне сервера, а PHP не работает на стороне клиента!

Comment: echo "<%- partial('content/product', {i: i, category: ".$_POST['category']." }) %>"; а почему этот код не работает?

Comment: Судя по коду, если у вас задано $_POST['category'] - все должно быть в порядке. Если у вас ошибка, как вы писали в предыдущем комментарии - где ее текст?